# Importing/re-using test files from another module in a pip package?

Tags: python, pip, init, directory-structure

### Context

As part of a pip package, I wrote a test which I would like to partially re-use for different configurations. (A single configuration takes +- 15 minutes (on my device), so ideally I would like to be able to test them separately, instead of sequentially in a single test). However, for the pip package I have the following folder structure:

```
Projectname/
|-- src/
|   |-- Projectname
|   |--|-- __init__.py
|   |--|-- main.py
|   |--|-- somefile.py
|
|-- tests/
|   |-- some_testfolder/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_one.py
|   |-- another_testfolder/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_two.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

Analogous to [the flake8 folder structure](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/blob/main/tests/__init__.py). And the example class that is to be imported is analogue to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29987595).

```py
class BasetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
     # ran by all subclasses

  def helper(self):
    # help

class TestCaseOne(BaseTestCase):

   def setUp(self):
      # additional setup
      super(TestCaseOne, self).setUp()

  def test_something(self):
      self.helper() # <- from base
```

However, when I try to import a class from `tests/test_one.py` I get the error:

```
================================================================================================== ERRORS ==================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/sparse/MDSA/test_snn_results_with_adaptation.py __________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/projectname/tests/some_testfolder/test_one.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/sparse/MDSA/test_snn_results_with_adaptation.py:8: in <module>
    from projectname.tests.some_testfolder.test_one import (
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname.tests'
====================================================================
```

I suspect this is because the root directory named `Projectname` does not have an `__init__` file. However, if I add one there, then I get the error:

```
No module named 'Projectname.somefile'
```

I think this is because then it starts looking from the root directory, which only contains the `src` folder, but not the `Projectname` folder.

However, I would expect the code to import from the pip package named `Projectname`, instead of from the `Projectname` folder.

### Question

Where should I place the `__init__` files such that I can import functions from other test files, whilst also preserving imports from the pip packages instead of directory names?

Answer (score 0):

The tests can be ran using:

```py
from tests.some_folder import (
    Test_one,
)
```

instead of:

```py
from Projectname.tests.some_folder import (
    Test_one,
)
```

No additional `__init__.py` files were required.